# How to Calculate a Permutation Test p-value

Tags: r, permutation-test

I've been working through the Hesterberg Bootstrap and Permutation Test Section Here:
http://hsta559s12.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/50747070/Hesterberg.Bootstrappng.chpt18.pdf
and I'm stuck on problem 18.49.  The problem basically asks to get an unpaired t-test p-value for two sets of Seattle home process (2001 vs 2002).  Then I need to perform a permutation test to show that the permutation p-value is similar to the t-test one.  However, I'm getting a permutation p-val of 0.22 instead of the expected 0.42.  I may be missing something trivial but I can't figure it out.  Thanks to anyone that can help.

```
library(stringr)
Seattle2001 <- as.numeric(str_extract_all("419 55.268 65 210 510.728 212.2 152.720 266.6 69.427 125
                                          191 451 469 310 325 50 675 140 105.5 285
                                          320 305 255 95.179 346 199 450 280 205.5 135
                                          190 452.5 335 455 291.905 239.9 369.95 569 481 475
                                          495 195 237.5 143 218.95 239 710 172 228.5 270","\\d+(\\.)?\\d+")[[1]])
Seattle2002 <- as.numeric(str_extract_all("142 232 132.5 200 362 244.95 335 324.5 222 225
                                          175 50 215 260 307 210.95 1370 215.5 179.8 217
                                          197.5 146.5 116.7 449.9 266 265 256 684.5 257 570
                                          149.4 155 244.9 66.407 166 296 148.5 270 252.95 507
                                          705 1850 290 164.95 375 335 987.5 330 149.95 190","\\d+(\\.)?\\d+")[[1]])
print(paste0("unpaied t-test p.val: ",t.test(Seattle2001,Seattle2002,paired = F)$p.value))
#> [1] "unpaied t-test p.val: 0.423057868164622"
#permutation test
all_prices = c(Seattle2001,Seattle2002)
group_label = c(rep("control",50),rep("treatment",50))
perm_mean_diff <- function(v,label) mean(v[label=="treatment"])-mean(v[label=="control"])
sample_mean_diff = perm_mean_diff(all_prices,group_label)
set.seed(1234)
perm_num =9999
perm_res <- sapply(1:perm_num,function(x) perm_mean_diff(all_prices,sample(group_label)))
perm_p_val = (sum(perm_res>=sample_mean_diff)+1)/(perm_num+1)
print(paste0("two sample permutation test p.val): ",perm_p_val))
#> [1] "two sample permutation test p.val): 0.2197"
Created on 2019-02-23 by the reprex package (v0.2.1)
```

Comment: Without even having looked at the problem, I suspect maybe you are doing a 2-sided test vs. a 1-sided test, since your $p$-value is about double the other?  Is that possible?

Comment: That makes sense.  The "book" answer given in the chapter is P=0.423 for the permutation test and I'm getting P=0.22.  If you look at how I implemented the solution, as far as I can tell I implemented a one-tail test.  So, I still don't get where I got off course!

Comment: You only counted "as, or more extreme" in one direction. You need both.